# shutdown /P - explanations

Tags: windows

I ask, after many attempts to understand-
Would it be true to say, the P switch is valid only in the next combinations and nothing more?

I think I understand Microsoft pages, but it seems so odd they have invents this switch for shutting down only.

```
Shutdown /P
Shutdown /P /F
```

Answer (score 0):

`Shutdown /?` says this on my Windows 11:

```
/p      Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
        Can be used with /d and /f options.
```

So it can be combined with:

```
/f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
           The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
           specified for the /t parameter.

/d [p|u:]xx:yy  Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
           p indicates that the restart or shutdown is planned.
           u indicates that the reason is user defined.
           If neither p nor u is specified the restart or shutdown is
           unplanned.
           xx is the major reason number (positive integer less than 256).
           yy is the minor reason number (positive integer less than 65536).
```

I assume that it can also be used with other flags that have no relation
to the shutdown process itself, such as for example:

```
/e         Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.

/m         \\computer Specify the target computer.
```